# Time series: Subtract subsequent values from initial value for multiple categories in single column

Tags: r

I have a df like this one:

```
cat<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
julian_day<-c(100,112,123,192,207,237,34,87,102)
dat<-data.frame(cat,julian_day)
```

In this example I have three categories each with three observations. I would like to subtract the 1st observation from each category from the subsequent observations and store this information in a new column.

The result would look like this:

```
cat<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
julian_day<-c(100,112,123,192,207,237,34,87,102)
difference<-c(0,12,23,0,15,45,0,23,68)
dat<-data.frame(cat,julian_day,difference)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave`

```
dat$difference <- ave(dat$julian_day,dat$cat,FUN=function(x)x-x[1])
```